# Angular 6 | AngularFireDatabase - return keys & values from object

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am struggling with understanding how to get data from a Firebase Realtime Database using Angular 6, AngularFireDatabase and using Ionic 3. There is a lot of conflicting information and using examples / approaches posted here hasn't been successful.

The data I am trying to display is structured as:

```
ID#
- title: "James N"
- email: "j@n.com"
- numitems: "2"
```

I've structured the original call in a service (profile.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()

export class Users{


details: Observable<any>;
id: string;


constructor (public db: AngularFireDatabase){};
    // console.log("uid in getdata: " + this.uid2);

    getData(id): Observable<any> {
      this.details = this.db.list('/ftuserprofiles/'+this.id).snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(items => {
        return items.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.val();
          const key = a.payload.key;
          return {key, data};
    });
  }));
      console.log('users.getdata() details: ' + this.details)
      return this.details;
    }

}
```

The service is called in the component. I have tried a number of ways here, but basically I am getting the ID# from a query which is working reliably and then passing that to the service as such:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Users } from './profile';
import {  NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Intercom } from '@ionic-native/intercom';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth/auth';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
// import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';




@Component({
  selector: 'page-garden',
  templateUrl: 'garden.html',
})
export class GardenPage {
  public items: any [] = [];
  public itemRef;
  public email$;
  public cdQ4;
  public title: string="";
  public numbeds:string="";
  public address:string="";
  public email:string="";
  public fields;
  public id: string="";
  uid2;

constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    // public http: HttpClient,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private intercom: Intercom,
    private data: DataProvider,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    public users: Users
  )
    {
      this.getUID();
      console.log('cid from getUID-constructor : ' + this.uid2);
      this.fields = this.users.getData(this.uid2).subscribe();
      console.log('this.fields : ', this.fields);
      console.log('this.fields : ' + this.fields.key);
}


    getUID() {
      this.email$ = this.auth.getEmailOnly();
      this.cdQ3 = firebase.database().ref('/ftuserprofiles')
.orderByChild('email')
.equalTo(this.email$);
      this.details = this.cdQ3.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        this.userDeets = [];
        snapshot.forEach( snap => {
            this.uid2 = snap.key;
                    console.log('cid from getUID-garden : ' + this.uid2);
                    return false;
                  });
      });
return this.uid2;
    }



ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad GardenPage');
    this.getUID();
    this.email$ = this.auth.getEmailOnly();

    this.cdQ4 = this.users.getData(this.uid2);

    this.address = this.fields['address'];
    this.title = this.fields.title;
    console.log('title ' + this.title);
}
}
```

Finally to display, I have (after much painful research around pipes) the following as a test to display what I'm getting:

```
<ion-header>
......
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
......
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of fields | keyvalue">

  {{ item.key }} - {{ item.value }}

  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I get console output of the following:

```
[app-scripts] [07:34:01]  console.log: Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 1588 ms 
[app-scripts] [07:34:02]  console.log: signed in user: 
[app-scripts] [07:34:02]  console.log: jeremy@avalow.com 
[app-scripts] [07:34:02]  console.log: intercom register user 
[app-scripts] [07:34:02]  console.log: intercom register for push 
[app-scripts] [07:34:03]  console.log: cid from getUID-constructor : undefined 
[app-scripts] [07:34:03]  console.log: users.getdata() details: [object Object] 
[app-scripts] [07:34:03]  console.log: this.fields : undefined 
[app-scripts] [07:34:03]  console.log: ionViewDidLoad GardenPage 
[app-scripts] [07:34:03]  console.log: users.getdata() details: [object Object] 
[app-scripts] [07:34:03]  console.log: title undefined 
[app-scripts] [07:34:03]  console.log: jeremy@avalow.com 
[app-scripts] [07:34:03]  console.log: cid from getUID-garden : 2a2a18f2-49e6-3daf-9208-ef3f67c15e12
```

and the current displayed result makes me feel like it's close? maybe???

[App output - displaying object wrapper?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuAEv.png)

I am trying to return "this.fields" as a subscribed snapshot of a database object that contains key / value pairs that can be displayed.  I have been unable to find anything that works in the last several days of looking. It can't be this hard to display fields from a database, right?

Any education or tips are greatly appreciated! I know I have a long way to go in getting up to speed and welcome all suggestions for resources!

Comment: At first sight a couple of things wrong. In the service: `return {key, data}`: I think you may want to decompose the `data` like this: `return {key, ...data}`. `this.fields = this.users.getData(this.uid2).subscribe();`: You're `this.fields` is a subsription this way. Try `this.users.getData(this.uid2).subscribe(users => this.fields = users)`. If you can create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) you're likely to get more response.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I will dive into modifying the subscriptions and creating a stackblitz

Comment: Stripped down the approach and put it in a stackblitz. Made progress of a sort, getting null in stackblitz, but getting an object if i hard-code the database path - https://angular-firetortbexample.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that the code populating `this.email$` has not completed by the time you use it in `firebase.database().ref...`. That's why you get some result when you hardcode it.

A solution would be to use an rxjs operator like `switchMap()`:

**component**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject, AngularFireAction } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {

  name = 'Firebase Data Test';
  public email$: Observable<string>;
  public person$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // I'm guessing this is an observable in your code
    // using of() for simplicity
    // this.email$ = this.auth.getEmailOnly();
    this.email$ = of('j@j.com');

    this.person$ = this.getData();
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {

    return this.email$.pipe(
        // switchMap returns a different observable for eacht emitted value by the source (this.email$)
        switchMap(email => { 
          // no need to use native firebase api, can be done with angularfire
          return this.db.list('ftuserprofiles', ref => 
              ref.orderByChild('email')
                 .equalTo(email)
                 .limitToFirst(1))
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(actions => actions.map(action =>  {
                const key = action.payload.key;
                const data = action.payload.val();
                return {key, ...data}
              }))
            )
        }));
  }
}
```

**template**:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<h3><pre>{{ person$ | async | json }}</pre></h3>
```

A modified & working version of your stackblitz can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firetortbexample-bbksbj)

Comment: Wow, thanks Tim! There are a couple of unfamiliar concepts that I need to brush up on, but this is so much simpler and easier to follow. Very appreciated!

Comment: How can I add error handling to the getData() ? Some of my users do not have access to that data and I want to handle the error and display it, but not sure how.
By the way, this solved my problem too. thanks!!!